# Resolution locked after fans went crazy

Tags: windows, drivers, hardware-failure, nvidia-graphics-card, gaming

Before I start: The issue I'm describing has already been resolved. However, I don't know what caused it, and would like to get some insight. I know that this is not exactly the scope of this site, so feel free to point me to a better place to ask my question if it's inappropriate.

Earlier today, I was playing a game (Hitman 2, if that matters) when my screens suddenly went black and the fans of my PC started to rotate at maximum speed. I quickly shut down my PC through holding down the power button. When I started it again, the resolution was locked to 1024x768 instead of my usual 1920x1200 and my second screen was not recognized at all. I eventually resolved the issue by installing the newest driver for my GeForce 2060 Super and everything is back to normal now.

Now, I'm not a hardware expert, but to me this looks like my graphics card went into some kind of save mode, limiting itself to lower settings in order to prevent damage to the hardware. **My question would be, if that is true and I should have my hardware checked up, or if it's indeed a driver problem that is now fixed for good (or at least until the next driver update).**

Also, this may or may not be related to a behavior I noticed several times in the past weeks, mainly when playing graphics-heavy games like Star Citizen. Out of a sudden, the framerate drops, the fans start spinning faster, and the task manager shows both my GPU and my CPU dropping in usage. This only lasts a brief moment, after which they quickly go back to usual usage and performance. In light of this recent incident however, I wonder if this could hint at an underlying hardware problem.

Comment: sounds like you have a thermal or electrical issue. no idea about the locked res, though I have encountered something like that before. I'd guess that the GPU is still too hot. I'd look into cooling your system more aggressively. start with a cleaning, test all your fans, make sure your air-flow is designed rationally, track down where components are overheating, and look into whether you need to replace or add additional fans/heatsinks.

Comment: I sympathize, but I'm not sure this belongs on a Q&A site - there's never going to be a single accepted answer. I'd suggest posting this on a site that's more discussion-based like Reddit...